# When taking an antiderivative of a dot product of two vectors, can I refactor as the addition of two antiderivatives of each individual vector?

Tags: integration

For example, if I have:

$$\int [\sin x \cos y + \sin y \cos x] dx$$

can I separate this into:

$$\left(\int [\sin x \cos x]\ dx\right) + \left(\int[\sin y\cos y]\ dx\right)$$

Comment: Why have you changed the cosines' arguments? For which $u$ do you want a $du$ in each integral?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out if I can factor out the dot product of [sinx,cosx] $\cdot$ [cosy,siny], either with multiplication or addition of the integral of each vector.  I realize this is a bit naive and I'm sure I'm making some basic error in how I'm asking the question... my apologies.

Comment: ah, thank you for the edits, @r-burton

Comment: I'm curious. Where did your question arise? Can you give a little insight into what the original problem was?

Comment: I think my question might be a little too specific.  I noticed that the original problem contains the dot product of two vectors, namely [sinx,cosx] $\cdot$ [cosy,sinx].  I think more broadly, I'm curious whether I  can separate that in the context of the original integration problem.  Maybe I should edit the question?  Would that help, and/or is that proper etiquette ?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be changing the cosines' arguments. The simplest solution is to rewrite your problem as $\int\sin(x+y)dx=-\cos(x+y)+C(y)$.